# Buscar Dados com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Se alguém puder me ajudar:

Estou fazendo um sistema em ASP.NET MVC de controle acadêmico. Na hora de fazer a matrícula, eu queria colocar um campo em branco para digitar o CPF, e outros campos como o nome, mas apenas pra apresentação, e pegar o id pra efetivar a matrícula.

Faria uma busca pelo CPF no *Controller* e retorna o aluno ou uma mensagem dizendo que o aluno não foi encontrado. Já tentei algumas funções mas sem sucesso.

Coloquei funções mais ou menos deste tipo:

```
<script>
    $('#cpf').change(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $("#nome").val('');
        $("#idAluno").val('');

        var cpf = $('#cpf').val();

        $.getJSON("/Cursos/RetornaAluno" + cpf + "&formato=json", {}, function (data) {

            if (data.aluno_txt != null) {

                $("#nome").val(data.nome);
                $("#idAluno").val(data.idAluno);

            }
            else {
                alert("Aluno não encontrado");
                $("#cpf").focus();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

E criei uma `ActionResult` no *Controller* que retorna o objeto. Nunca tinha usado jQuery então não sei como fazer.

```
    public ActionResult RetornaAluno(string cpf)
    {
        var aluno = from a in db.Alunos select a;
        aluno = aluno.Where(a => a.cpfAluno == cpf);

        return Json(aluno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Ok, agora preciso do código do *Controller* também.

Answer (score 1):

Isto aqui está errado:

```
$.getJSON("/Cursos/RetornaAluno" + cpf + "&formato=json", {}, function (data) { ... });
```

Possivelmente a rota padrão nem aceita CPF como argumento, então você precisa especificar o nome do parâmetro na URL. Ou seja:

```
$.getJSON("/Cursos/RetornaAluno/?cpf=" + cpf, {}, function (data) { ... });
```

Sobre o *Controller*, algumas coisas me chamaram a atenção:

```
public ActionResult RetornaAluno(string cpf)
{
    var aluno = from a in db.Alunos select a;
    aluno = aluno.Where(a => a.cpfAluno == cpf);

    return Json(aluno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Isto:

```
var aluno = from a in db.Alunos select a;
aluno = aluno.Where(a => a.cpfAluno == cpf);
```

Pode ser substituído por isto:

```
var aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.cpfAluno == cpf);
```

O primeiro motivo é a performance. Aqui:

```
var aluno = from a in db.Alunos select a;
```

Você está trazendo todos os alunos para a memória da aplicação, para selecionar apenas um registro. Nada bom em desempenho.

O segundo motivo é a simplicidade.

Possivelmente isto aqui está errado também:

```
        if (data.aluno_txt != null) {
            $("#nome").val(data.nome);
            $("#idAluno").val(data.idAluno);
        }
        else {
            alert("Aluno não encontrado");
            $("#cpf").focus();
        }
```

Se o aluno não for encontrado, `data` vem vazio. Portanto, teste se `data` inteiro procede, da seguinte forma:

```
        if (data) {
            $("#nome").val(data.nome);
            $("#idAluno").val(data.idAluno);
        }
        else {
            alert("Aluno não encontrado");
            $("#cpf").focus();
        }
```

Com isso deve funcionar.

Comment: vlw mesmo... ainda não deu certo, ele não ta encontrando o objeto na action, mas a função Jquery ta funcionando...Muito obrigado

Comment: Como assim? Você colocou um *breakpoint* na *Action* pra testar?

Comment: Sim, a Action está recebendo o parâmetro, mas a varável retorna Null. Se eu coloco da outra forma, diz q a enumeração não gerou resultados